# Use of undeclared identifier [objective-c]

Tags: objective-c

i have an Object_Info.h (contains the interface declaration) and Object_Info.m (contains some not all method implementations) files in the same directory as my main.m.

in main.m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Object_Info.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        error thrown here -> use of undeclared identifier 'tempObjInfo'
        (Object_Info*) tempObjInfo = [[Object_Info alloc] init];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

any ideas as to why the error is there? `user of undeclared identifier 'tempObjInfo'`

I've tried `(Object_Info*) tempObjInfo = [Object_Info new]` as well with no success.

Thanks!

Comment: Drop the brackets: `Object_Info* tempObjInfo = ...`

Answer (score 1):

You didn't declare the identifier. You should declare it like...

```
Object_Info *tempObjInfo = [[Object_Info alloc] init];
```

... or if the tempObjInfo symbol is declared somewhere globally you will need to include the header where it is being declared.

Comment: Not that much. `(Object_Info*)`, that's casting. But that's not declaring, and in C it's that way.